# How to call an asmx webservice with client-side-only code?

Tags: .net, ajax, web-services, json

So, google and stack are garbled with many different approaches to this problem, which I thought would be easily researchable.

I want to know the best/cleanest way to call a .net .asmx based webservice, from pure javascript client side code.  i.e. No  tags.  Nearly every reference to this question provides asp.net server-side code examples, which I don't want.

I guess I could use jquery on the client side.  I think (but am unsure) that Microsoft has a client-side javascript library that can be used to make an ajax call to a webservice as well.

I'm happy to modify my server-side asmx webservice to be JSON compatible (i.e. the client-side code here doesn't have to handle soap).

Must I adopt jquery?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: For those who have the same question but are happy to use jquery, http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ is a good resource on how to use jquery to call asmx based webservices.

Note the breaking change between asp.net 2 and asp.net 3.5 that introduces the use of .d (see this great explanation (http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same question, my research has shown that the safest approach to this is to harness a client-side library.  In the end I've gone with JQuery on the client side, coupled with JSON enabled asmx based webservices (subject to the links in the comments above)

Comment: is your webservice a cross domain webservice?